# Proper data structure in firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to firebase and I'm not sure I am storing data properly.

I am building a form to store data. Right now it only has 2 fields, however I will be adding a few more input fields later.

My form HTML looks like this:

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <input placeholder="Event Title..." class="form-control" name="eventTitle" ng-model="newEvent.title">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input placeholder="random..." class="form-control" name="eventRandom" ng-model="newEvent.random">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="addEvent(newEvent);newEvent = null;">send</button>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
.controller('ChatCtrl', function ($scope, Ref, $firebaseArray, $timeout) {
// synchronize a read-only, synchronized array of events, limit to most recent 10
$scope.events = $firebaseArray(Ref.child('events').limitToLast(10));

// display any errors
$scope.events.$loaded().catch(alert);

// provide a method for adding a event
$scope.addEvent = function(newEvent) {
  if( newEvent ) {
    console.dir('newEvent: '+ newEvent);
    // push a event to the end of the array
    $scope.events.$add({newEvent})
      // display any errors
      .catch(alert);
  }
};
```

In firebase, the data looks like this:

[image]

The "newEvent" node seems entirely redundant. I'm not sure how to code my form and controller properly. All the examples I seem to find on the internet use a chat room as an example, and the send form only contains a single textarea field.

I did find an example with more than one field and it showed the above example, however like I pointed out, the "newEvent" node seems redundant after the firebase generated key.

What is the proper way to code a form with multiple input fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to get rid of the `newEvent` and purely set up the structure as so:

```
events
    push-key
        random: "random",
        title: "event title"
    push-key
        ...
```

The change how you `$add` the data:

```
$scope.events.$add({ title: newEvent.title, random: newEvent.random })
// display any errors
.catch(alert);
```

You are pushing an object with the structure:

```
newEvent
    random: "random",
    title: "event title"
```

which will insert that entire object under the push key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It makes more sense now. I didn't understand that I was actually pushing an object. I do have a question. Eventually, these "events" will need to be displayed as a list. They will also be associated with a user that creates the event. Lastly, these will be queried by title, and also by date, as well as by a geo-coordinate. (The last two inputs I have not added to the form yet.) Is there an advantage to storing the object over just storing data under a push-key in this scenario?

Comment: Most likely not for your events. But if you had a tree that could contain multiple instances of the same type then you want to store underneath an object. If you are guaranteed to ever only have **one** instance of your form (random, title, etc) then you don't need the parent object.